# TInyPNG integration with Google App Engine Datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, image-compression

I need to fetch images from different URLs and store it in Google Datastore after compressing it. I understand tinyPNG is the a great API to do the compression but the API only supports Amazon S3.

Can someone guide how to accomplish this in Google App Engine.

Answer (score 3):

The S3-only support you mentioned applies only to **directly** uploading the compressed images **from their server** (i.e. without passing them through the application making the image compression requests), which is just a convenience feature. From [the tinypng docs](https://tinypng.com/developers/reference):

> Uploading to Amazon S3
>
> You can tell the Tinify API to upload compressed images directly to
>   Amazon S3. If you use S3 to host your images this saves you the hassle
>   of downloading images to your server and uploading them to S3
>   yourself.

Your app should be able to download the compressed images using their REST API and save them to the datastore.

Answer (score 1):

Since the Google App Engine is read only, you can't write files to it with the built-in tinify functions. You can, though, use blob storage in the App Engine. Make sure you have the tinify code and requests module (which tinify uses) in a libs folder in your GAE app. I needed version 2.3 of requests in order for tinify to work.

To use image storage with GAE, define a database model for an entity with blob storage, something like:

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb

class Image(ndb.Model):
    img = ndb.BlobProperty()
```

Now we need a function in tinify that writes to blob storage of an entity instead of writing to a file. You can mirror the existing tinify code for writing to file:

In the `source.py` file, add this method:

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb

class Source(object):
    ...
    def to_blob(self, key):
        return self.result().to_blob(key)
    ...
```

And in the `result.py` file add this method:

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb

class Result(ResultMeta):
    ...
    def to_blob(self, key):
        img_store = key.get()
        img_store.img = self.data
    ...
```

Now tinify can write in GAE that you can serve however you want. You just need to create an entity, pass the key to the Source.to_blob() method and your entity will now have the compressed image stored. So now you can do:

```
class Basepage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
    ...
        img_store = Image()
        img_key = img_store.put()

        # Use URL for image to be compressed
        source = tinify.from_url("http://...")
        source.to_blob(img_key)

        compressed_img_store = img_key.get()

        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'image/png'
        self.response.out.write(compressed_img_store.img)
```